# Use Drupal search to search Q2A and PHPBB content

Tags: php, html, drupal, phpbb, question2answer

Q2A and PHPBB are 2 branches of my main website.

In other words..

website.com/q2a

and

website.com/phpbb

...

When I use the login box on any of the 3 branches, I want the SSO to log me in to all 3 branches.

When I use the search box on any of the 3 branches, I want it to search content from all branches.

When I click on a user profile on any of the 3 branches, I want it to always go to the same user profile page.

Is this possible? How?

Will I need to make a custom CMS and a custom Q&A PHP Script and a Custom Forums?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can integrate them all to use a single userbase (and/or search index) for sure. However, unless you find a ready bridge that accommodates them all, you will need to:

- study each application's databases and map the way they store users and data,
- build hooks into the source code on each (unless they support this via an API),
- and have a master frame that initiates logged-in sessions and keeps data in mutual sync.

May not be a trivial task. Then again, creating matching applications from a scratch isn't a trivial task either. But of course we should all create our own CMS and app frameworks. What else is there to do.

Comment: You're a great source of information Markus. I wish I could thumbs up your profile 15 times. I think I'm going to do away with trying to combine 3 different platforms.. and instead just work on 1 that has it all built in already. Anything is possible, right? :)

Comment: Glad to educate and entertain. I once created a CMS framework with page builders and 20 odd modules in three months, so yes stuff can happen if you are mad enough. I imagine if you look into the mainstream CMS platforms, you will be able to find bridge modules that can integrate popular forums etc. under one hood. Good luck finding a bridge that supports all the latest versions in a timely fashion though.